# Issue with a to-many relationship which not update in persistent store

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I have an issue with Core Data in my project.

I have a NSManagedObject subclass (called CDMPDFExportModel) with a to-many relationship to CDMBankAccount objects (called bankAccounts).

When I create a new CDMPDFExportModel, with some bankAccounts, and then I save context, it works fine. When I restart the app, the bankAccounts remain the same.

But when I edit them, by removing for example one of the bankAccounts, and then saving context again (without getting any error), it works until app is closed. After, when I restart it, the changes are restored (only for the bankAccounts relationship), as if the context has not been saved to the persistent store...

I have this issue only with the bankAccount relationship, the other ones work fine (and are successfully saved after editing)...

I spent 2 days trying fixing it, but it still doesn't work...

If someone could help me... :))

Thanks a lot

Thomas

EDIT : I have this issue only on my iPhone (it works correctly on the simulator...)

Comment: Its hard to figure out what your doing wrong if you don't post a snippet of code. But anyway try setting the bank account object in the CDMPDFExportModel to nil and save the context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm going to try. Also, I've edited my post, because I noticed this issue only happens on my real device (it works fine on the simulator). This is very strange..

Comment: What does your core data stack look like? When are you saving? Are you certain that your save code is firing?

Comment: What do you call "core data stack"? In my case I've a very basic config, with a single context connected to a persistent store. The context is saved just after the changes are made, and the code is firing well since I get the correct NSLog statements, and above all, the other changes (on other properties of the managed object) are saved..

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed my issue!

In fact, I just had to create the inverse relationship of `CDMPDFExportModel.bankAccounts` (as a many-to-many relationship).

I don't know why it didn't work without that (I don't have to use this inverse relationship, I don't even declared the dynamic property), but it seems to work fine now...

Thank you for your help